# Add syntax highlighting for [ballerina]

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I've submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/552) to code-prettify adding syntax highlighting for [Ballerina](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ballerina) more than two months ago. But apparently code-prettify is not maintained anymore and it's not been merged yet.

Is there a chance this can be integrated into Stack Overflow?

Comment: I, for one, am disappointed the ballerina is not pretty. :P

Answer (score 6):

Realistically, that's very unlikely.

SE already supports only a subset of what Prettify supports to reduce size and load time, and adding a language that prettify doesn't support for a tag with less than 1000 questions seems unlikely to me.

For example, Mathematica support, while present on [mathematica.se](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), is scrapped here to save page load time, even though it has ~4000 questions.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I'll look into providing this as a stack apps script or some such for ballerina enthusiasts.

Comment: That sounds like a conditional load on the pages which have an offband language to me...

Comment: @Luke that's not how syntax highlighting currently works. All pages get the full minified library with all supported languages

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Im sure that you are right, but with all of the great chunking tools we now have available Im sure it wouldn't be too hard to conditionally load some extra bits for specific tags