# Set highlighter for julia tag to lang-default?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed that there is no syntax highlighting on block code under the [juliag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juliag) tag in SO. Basically, how do we set a highlighter to be used by default with the [julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/julia) tag? It seems like the default highlighter (I believe "lang-default") works.

An example where it is not working, taken from [Julia error: no method matching strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824445/julia-error-no-method-matching-strange-behavior)

[image]

Comment: Use `<!-- language: lang-default -->`  on a line in front of a code block.

Comment: Sure, you can add tags for specific highlighting to your code blocks, but nobody does that, and I'm not going to go through and add them to the entire repository of questions under that tag. This should be automatic.

Comment: The first question is tagged [tag:json] and that tag has the [default highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info) (see the bottomn of that page). [tag:julia-lang] has no [highlighter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/julia-lang/info) so it defaults to `lang-none` See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327673/what-is-the-default-language-for-the-syntax-highlighter/327677#327677

Comment: @rene thanks! How do we get the default highligher set for Julia then? Seems to work fine, but "just add the tag manually to every post ever" isn't a workable solution.

Comment: What you could do is asking to add [a suitable code highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) to be added to the julia-lang tag. If no suitable option exists, see if lang-default will work as a best effort

Comment: @rene updated with your information: I am now asking to have the highlighter for Julia set to the default highlighter, which seems to work fine. If meta isn't the right place to do it, then what is?

Comment: A moderator can handle it but it might need to sit here a couple of days in case someone comes up with a reason why this is a bad idea

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373774/add-syntax-highlighting-for-ballerina)

Comment: The [ballerina highlighting question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373774/add-syntax-highlighting-for-ballerina) that has been linked twice (three times now) is not related. That's a question wherein somebody added their own highlighting rules to code-prettify via a pull request and asked about getting them incorporated on SO. Seems like it was not supported. Here I believe we just need the default prettifier.

Comment: There exists (now?) a highlight mode for julia, suitably named `lang-julia`, I activated it per language hint and [it's working fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949628/julia-integrating-differential-equations-methoderror-no-method-matching). @rene

Comment: @LutzL I'm pretty sure you're looking at the handler for lang-default which is used as a fallback, catch all in case no specific handler exist. There is no `julia` [here](https://dev.sstatic.net/js/prettify-full.en.js).

Comment: @rene Ok, then the default is pretty good at guessing keywords, types and comments there.

Comment: @LutzL it is pretty [extensive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327677/578411) ...

Comment: There is still no automatic syntax highlighting for `julia` tag

Comment: @J.Khamphousone at +4/-3 you can't say there seems to be overwhelming support to add it.

Comment: To me this seems like a no-brainer. If a prettifier exists that does not directly obfuscate the meaning of code, it's better than no prettifier for code readability. Just set the default prettifier for Julia and be done with it. Improves the overall appearance and readability of questions with that tag and nobody is hurt. This shouldn't be something that takes a committee six months to debate...

Comment: I have been trying to get this prettifier and another default prettifier for Tensorflow set for way too long now. This might be a separate meta discussion, but the process for supporting new languages that do not currently have a default prettifier seems broken. Julia and TF have both been out long enough that the lack of support seems to imply SO is unable to change with the times. I don't think that's the impression that anyone in this community wants to give.

Comment: Why was this marked as completed? In the example linked above, the code blocks are identified and highlighted as SIX different languages (Delphi, less, PHP, coffeescript, C#, and INI) ... and are not using the default parser.  But we can do even better: Julia is now officially supported by HighlightJS by default.

Comment: Compared to other supported languages, [tag:julia] has more questions than [tag:ini], [tag:lisp], [tag:protobuf], [tag:ocaml], [tag:scheme], [tag:vhdl], and slightly less than [tag:erlang].

Comment: @MattB. This was marked as completed because it has been done, precisely as requested. The [julia] tag's default syntax highlighting has been set to "lang-default", as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuZJV.png. Julia syntax highlighting isn't supported by Stack Exchange; see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109. There's no option for us to choose "julia" or "lang-julia". So that would need to be a separate feature request, and not one actionable by moderators.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for the answer. I didn’t understand  what it means to have the default highlighter chosen for the tag (and still don’t get it; I thought lang-default was itself a generic language spec that should be used instead of haphazardly picking schemes). But no matter — I’ve found the better plan of action here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355928/julia-syntax-highlighting

Comment: @MattB. Nice find; thanks. I've upvoted that feature request. `lang-default` is...the default. It basically just lets Highlight.JS parse the code and guess at what it considers to be "reasonable" syntax highlighting. It's basically the alternative to setting `lang-none` as the default, which is probably not what you want. Not that `lang-default` is all that much better. The purpose of setting the default syntax highlighter for a tag is so that all posts having that tag, where the language is not explicitly set in the code block, will be highlighted using that tag's default.